# Laravel 8 Eloqunet: How to set OR condition to where clause in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to show all the Orders from `orders` table where the `status` field of that table, equals to `canceled` **OR** `ignored`.

Currently my query goes like this:

```
$canceled = Order::where('status', 'canceled')
                  ->where('user_id', $uid)
                   ->latest()
                   ->paginate(2);
```

So how can I add `ignored` as well to the `where` clause here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `whereIn` will do the trick

```
$canceled = Order::whereIn('status', ['canceled','ignored'])
                   ->where('user_id', $uid)
                   ->latest()
                   ->paginate(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
$canceled = Order::where(function($q) {
                   $q->where('status', 'canceled')
                      ->orWhere('status', 'ignored');
                    })
                    ->where('user_id', $uid)
                    ->latest()
                    ->paginate(2);
```